# suggestions to replace all links with redirect looks like adfly full page converter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, redirect

Thanks in advance these question is updated from other

trying to create simple redirect page to open external links

Here , i need to change `href` with `class="external"` from the root (recreate it) , not to create click event to open window with customized href

my question's answer looks like adfly full page converter thats convert all links in apage to http: + adf.ly + folder_id + link

```
<a class="external" href="http://google.com">GOOGLE</a>
<a class="external" href="http://facebook.com">facebook</a>
<a class="external" href="http://twitter.com">facebook</a>
```

see this

```
$('a.external').click(function (e) { 
        e.preventDefault(); 
        var target = e.target || e.srcElement; 
        if ($(target).attr('target') == "_blank") { 
          window.open("http://"+redirectpage+"?url=" +$(target).attr('href') , "_blank"); 
        } else { 
            window.location = "http://"+redirectpage +"?url="+ $(target).attr('href')); 
        }
    });
```

the above example dont replace links from http:// google .com/

to

http://example.com/redirect.html?url=http://google.com/

but when you click it open the link good

the redirect page i use http:// example .com/redirect.html

contains this

**html**

```
<a id="gotoexternal" href="">go to external</a>
```

**js**

```
<script> 
    var query = window.location.search.substring(1); 
    query = query.replace("url=", ""); 
    $('#gotoexternal').attr('href', query);  
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this :

```
 var redirectpage= "xxxxxx.com";
$('.external').each(
    function(){
    $(this).attr("href", "http://"+redirectpage+"?url="
 +$(this).attr('href') ); 

    $(this).attr("target","_blank");
    }


)
```

Here is a jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/tdybqpy2/1/

PS: I hate pages with adfly, I would never use your site, or i would do the script to remove the adfly links ;)

Comment: hahh :D thanx Luis :) i hate it alsooooo , 

your code open link in _blank empty page !!

Comment: did you check the jsfiddle? for me it open the right page.

Comment: I changed the target, that was not working :)

Comment: thanQ you are perfect , but my problem now that i load vars from another js file .. should i add var redirectpage ="xxx.com"; line above the code ???

Comment: Load the file before this code and add the code I wrote into the Document ready.

Comment: <script></script> // javascript file contains vars
<script>
$('.external').each(
    function(){
    $(this).attr("href", "http://"+redirectpage+"?url="
 +$(this).attr('href') , "_blank"); 
    }
);
</script>